# Unable to run JUnit 5 test case on latest Eclipse Jee 2019-09

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I had some issue(content assist) with old eclipse(Photon), so switched to latest eclipse jee 2019.
so when am trying to run some junit 5 unit tests which used to work before is now not able to recognize as Junit5 test case and throwing below error.

[image]

am getting below error messge too:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/TestPlan;[Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener;)V
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)**

Could some help with this ?

Comment: Does deleting the launch configuration fix your issue. By the way, Eclipse 2019-12 is the latest version. The screenshot in your answer shows an JDK and an JRE which looks odd.

Comment: @howlger accidental i added that. just removed and updated. But that didnt affect anything

Comment: Does deleting the launch configuration fix your issue?

Comment: No it didnt fix. i have to add junit library on build like i showed in my answer, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The only work around i found for my issue is :

add Junit5 library on the build path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed issue on my Eclipse.